# Can I install existing Strapi project locally?

Tags: strapi

I have to install strapi in my local. I have existing strapi project, my question is can I install existing project in my local env or there is only option to create new project?

Answer (score 1):

How about simply creating a directory, copy your project to the new directory, [Make sure requirements are met](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/installation/cli.html#step-1-make-sure-requirements-are-met) and [Start the project](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/installation/cli.html#step-3-start-the-project).
So basically instead of step 2 in the docs (create new Strapi project) you simply copy your existing one into the directory.
Worked for me.

Comment: Hmm seems like a good idea, but how can I download whole Strapi project from my strapi cms admin panel? :)

Comment: Not from the panel, from the server serving it or even better - a git project :)

Comment: Ok cool, thank you very much. Do you know maybe how can I fetch data from Strapi and display into my theme "bigcommerce" (https://www.bigcommerce.com/)? I cant figure out how to connect and configure Strapi content with my theme? I have config file but Im not sure what should I put here -> I have config.json file in my theme ->

"settings":{ 
"strapi_base_url" : "htttp://...",
"integration_server_base_url": which link I should add here/what is integration server?                                           
}      I know this is a little bit side question, any help would be nice, thanks! :)

Comment: Basically you can just make API calls to your strapi instance. So you can keep working with whatever you have been before.